# ¿Cómo evito que un div se comporte en bloque si la pantalla del navegador se reduce?

Tags: html, css

estoy diseñando una página web para clase.
Si la pantalla de mi navegador está completa se muestra algo tal como esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De tal forma que se divide en los siguientes divs:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta ahí todo va bien, pero si reduzco la pantalla de mi navegador, el div #noticias se desplaza hacia abajo a la izquierda:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero evitar es que cuando la ventana del navegador se haga mas pequeña, el div #noticias se desplace hacia abajo a la izquierda.
Quiero que se mantenga al lado de el div #principal siempre, aunque la ventana del navegador sea mas pequeña.

**Aclaro que no se puede usar media querys ni propiedades como grid.**

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=es>
<head>

<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>Noticias de Monte Olimpo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/estilos.css">

</head>
<body>

<div id="cabecera">
    <h1>Noticias del Olimpo</h1>
</div>
<div id="extras">
    <h2>Enlaces a las Historias</h2>
    <ul id="historias">
        <li><a href="">Jupiter & Su Poderosa Compañía</a></li>
        <li><a href="">La Edad de Oro</a></li>
        <li><a href="">La Historia de Prometeo</a></li>
        <li><a href="">El Diluvio</a></li>
        <li><a href="">La Historia de Io</a></li>
        <li><a href="">La Tejedora Maravillosa</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Cadmo y Europa</a></li>
        <li><a href="">La Cabeza de Medusa</a></li>
        <li><a href="">La Historia de Atlanta</a></li>
        <li><a href="">El Caballo y el Olivo</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
<div id="principal">
    <h2>Prometeo calienta el ambiente</h2>
    <p>A Prometeo no le importaba vivir en medio de las nubes, en la cima de la montaña. Estaba demasiado ocupado para eso. Mientras que los Dioses perdían su tiempo ociosos, bebiendo néctar y comiendo ambrosía, él planeaba hacer un mundo mejor y más sabio de lo que nunca lo había sido.</p>
    <p>Se mezcló con los hombres para vivir con ellos y ayudarlos. ¡Ah, cuán pobre y miserables eran! Los encontró viviendo en cuevas y en agujeros en la tierra, temblando de frío porque no había fuego, muriendo de hambre, perseguidos por las fieras y entre ellos, la más miserable de todas las criaturas vivientes.</p> 
    <p>"Si al menos tuvieran fuego", se dijo a Prometeo a sí mismo,"al menos podrían calentarse y cocinar su comida, y después de un tiempo podrían aprender a fabricar herramientas y construirse sus casas. Sin fuego están peor que las bestias"</p>
    <p>Se presentó ante Júpiter con valentía y le rogó dar el fuego a los hombres, para que pudieran tener un poco de consuelo en los largos y tristes meses de invierno.</p>
    <p>"No les doy ni una chispa", dijo Júpiter. "No, ni de broma. ¿Por qué?. Si los hombres tuvieran fuego podrían llegar a ser fuertes y sabios como nosotros, y después de un tiempo nos echarían fuera de nuestro reino. Lo mejor es que sean pobres e ignorantes para que que nosotros los Poderosos podamos prosperar y ser felices".</p>
    <p>Prometeo no respondió, pero había puesto su corazón en ayudar a la humanidad, y no se dio por vencido. Se dio la vuelta y abandonó para siempre a Júpiter y su poderosa compañía.</p>
    <p>Paseando por la orilla del mar encontró con una caña, o, como dicen algunos, un tallo alto de hinojo, crecido, y cuando lo había roto vio que su centro hueco estaba llenó con una médula suave y seca, que se quema lentamente en el fuego y lo mantiene bastante tiempo. Tomó el tallo largo en sus manos y se dirigio con él hacia la morada del sol en el lejano oriente.</p> 
    <p>"La humanidad tendrá fuego a pesar del tirano que está sentado en la cima de la montaña", dijo.</p>
    <p>Llegó a la morada del sol por la mañana temprano justo cuan la brillante y dorada orbe se estaba levantando de la tierra y comenzaba su viaje diario a través del cielo. Él tocó las llamas con la punta de la caña y la médula seca se incendió y ardió lentamente. Llamó a algunos de los hombres temblorosos en sus cuevas y encendió un fuego para ellos, y les mostró cómo construir otros fuegos de los carbones. Pronto hubo un resplandor alegre en todas las casas humildes, y los hombres y mujeres se reunieron alrededor de él y era cálido y feliz, y agradecían a Prometeo por el maravilloso regalo que había traído desde el sol. </p>
    <p>No pasó mucho tiempo hasta que aprendieron a cocinar sus alimentos y así comer como los hombres en vez de como las bestias. Comenzaron de inmediato a dejar sus hábitos salvajes y en lugar de esconderse en los lugares oscuros del mundo, salieron fuera al aire libre y a la luz del sol, y se alegraron porque les habían dado la vida.</p>
</div>
<div id="noticias">
<h2>Noticias</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><strong>¡Pandora abre la caja!</strong><br /> Liberadas para la eternidad las plagas de enfermedad y dolor. <a href="foo">Más...</a></li>
        <li><strong>Bienvenido a Helena.</strong><br /> El hijo de Prometeo escapa al diluvio y crea una sociadad en las piedras. <a href="foo">Más...</a></li>
        <li><strong>Una Red Enmarañada</strong><br /> 
            Aracne pierde el hilo; se transforma en araña. <a href="">Más...</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<div id="pie">
    <p>Contenido traducido de <cite>Old Greek Stories</cite> by James Baldwin (1914). It is a copyright free text available at <a href="http://www.gutenberg.net/1/1/5/8/11582/">Project Gutenberg</a>.
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
#cabecera{
    background: #CCCCCC;
    border: 1px solid;
}
#principal {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    max-width:100%;
    height:850px;
    border:1px solid;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
#extras {
    float: left;
    width: 35%;
    max-width:100%;
    height:850px;
    border:1px solid;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
#noticias{
    float:left;
    width:24.6%;
    height:850px;
    border:1px solid;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    min-width:200px;
} 
    
#pie {
    clear: left;
    border: 1px solid;
    background: gray;
}
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es la razón del que no se puede usar media querys ni grid?...

Comment: Es para un trabajo de clase. El profesor me lo requiere así, ya que quiere que consigamos un efecto de 3 (falsas) columnas 'de abajo a arriba' fluidas

Comment: Utiliza **flexbox** puede ayudar a distribuir el espacio entre los ítems de una interfaz y mejorar las capacidades de alineación.

Comment: Podrías decirme como?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tendrías que crear un `div` padre que encierre a los 3 `divs`, tal como te mencionan en la otra respuesta:

```
<div class="contenido">
  <div id="principal"></div>
  <div id="extra"></div>
  <div id="noticias"></div>
</div>
```

Y ese `div` tendría que ser flexible para que los elementos de adentro estén uno al lado del otro, con la siguiente propiedad:

```
.contenido {
  display: flex;
}
```

---

Ahora, para solucionar el error que comentas, los 3 elementos tienen que ocupar toda la altura máxima, es decir, si uno de los elementos es mas grande que el otro, los demás tendrán esa misma altura por igual:

```
#principal {
    /*...*/
    max-height: 100%;
}

#extras {
    /*...*/
    max-height: 100%;
}

#noticias{
    /*...*/
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

---

[**Código completo.**](https://codepen.io/christopher-ps/pen/oNMaeGV)

Comment: Muchas gracias eso resolvió lo del texto

Comment: Me alegro, un placer ayudarle, saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Ya que no puedes usar grid ni media query, una solución simple puede ser envolver las 3 secciones en un div contenedor al cual le vas a aplicar la propiedad display flex (ya que no lo mencionaste dentro de las restricciones).

**El html:**

```
<div id="contenedor">
  <div id="principal"></div>
  <div id="extra"></div>
  <div id="noticias"></div>
</div>
```

**y en el css**

```
#contenedor {
  display: flex
}
```

Y es asi como queda:

```css
@charset "utf-8";
#cabecera{
    background: #CCCCCC;
    border: 1px solid;
}

#contenedor {
  display: flex
}

#principal {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    max-width:100%;
    height:850px;
    border:1px solid;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
#extras {
    float: left;
    width: 35%;
    max-width:100%;
    height:850px;
    border:1px solid;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
#noticias{
    float:left;
    width:24.6%;
    height:850px;
    border:1px solid;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    min-width:200px;
} 
    
#pie {
    clear: left;
    border: 1px solid;
    background: gray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=es>

<head>

  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <title>Noticias de Monte Olimpo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/estilos.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div id="cabecera">
    <h1>Noticias del Olimpo</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="contenedor">

    <div id="extras">
      <h2>Enlaces a las Historias</h2>
      <ul id="historias">
        <li><a href="">Jupiter & Su Poderosa Compañía</a></li>
        <li><a href="">La Edad de Oro</a></li>
        <li><a href="">La Historia de Prometeo</a></li>
        <li><a href="">El Diluvio</a></li>
        <li><a href="">La Historia de Io</a></li>
        <li><a href="">La Tejedora Maravillosa</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Cadmo y Europa</a></li>
        <li><a href="">La Cabeza de Medusa</a></li>
        <li><a href="">La Historia de Atlanta</a></li>
        <li><a href="">El Caballo y el Olivo</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="principal">
      <h2>Prometeo calienta el ambiente</h2>
      <p>A Prometeo no le importaba vivir en medio de las nubes, en la cima de la montaña. Estaba demasiado ocupado para eso. Mientras que los Dioses perdían su tiempo ociosos, bebiendo néctar y comiendo ambrosía, él planeaba hacer un mundo mejor y más sabio
        de lo que nunca lo había sido.</p>
      <p>Se mezcló con los hombres para vivir con ellos y ayudarlos. ¡Ah, cuán pobre y miserables eran! Los encontró viviendo en cuevas y en agujeros en la tierra, temblando de frío porque no había fuego, muriendo de hambre, perseguidos por las fieras y
        entre ellos, la más miserable de todas las criaturas vivientes.</p>
      <p>"Si al menos tuvieran fuego", se dijo a Prometeo a sí mismo,"al menos podrían calentarse y cocinar su comida, y después de un tiempo podrían aprender a fabricar herramientas y construirse sus casas. Sin fuego están peor que las bestias"</p>
      <p>Se presentó ante Júpiter con valentía y le rogó dar el fuego a los hombres, para que pudieran tener un poco de consuelo en los largos y tristes meses de invierno.</p>
      <p>"No les doy ni una chispa", dijo Júpiter. "No, ni de broma. ¿Por qué?. Si los hombres tuvieran fuego podrían llegar a ser fuertes y sabios como nosotros, y después de un tiempo nos echarían fuera de nuestro reino. Lo mejor es que sean pobres e ignorantes
        para que que nosotros los Poderosos podamos prosperar y ser felices".</p>
      <p>Prometeo no respondió, pero había puesto su corazón en ayudar a la humanidad, y no se dio por vencido. Se dio la vuelta y abandonó para siempre a Júpiter y su poderosa compañía.</p>
      <p>Paseando por la orilla del mar encontró con una caña, o, como dicen algunos, un tallo alto de hinojo, crecido, y cuando lo había roto vio que su centro hueco estaba llenó con una médula suave y seca, que se quema lentamente en el fuego y lo mantiene
        bastante tiempo. Tomó el tallo largo en sus manos y se dirigio con él hacia la morada del sol en el lejano oriente.</p>
      <p>"La humanidad tendrá fuego a pesar del tirano que está sentado en la cima de la montaña", dijo.</p>
      <p>Llegó a la morada del sol por la mañana temprano justo cuan la brillante y dorada orbe se estaba levantando de la tierra y comenzaba su viaje diario a través del cielo. Él tocó las llamas con la punta de la caña y la médula seca se incendió y ardió
        lentamente. Llamó a algunos de los hombres temblorosos en sus cuevas y encendió un fuego para ellos, y les mostró cómo construir otros fuegos de los carbones. Pronto hubo un resplandor alegre en todas las casas humildes, y los hombres y mujeres
        se reunieron alrededor de él y era cálido y feliz, y agradecían a Prometeo por el maravilloso regalo que había traído desde el sol. </p>
      <p>No pasó mucho tiempo hasta que aprendieron a cocinar sus alimentos y así comer como los hombres en vez de como las bestias. Comenzaron de inmediato a dejar sus hábitos salvajes y en lugar de esconderse en los lugares oscuros del mundo, salieron
        fuera al aire libre y a la luz del sol, y se alegraron porque les habían dado la vida.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="noticias">
      <h2>Noticias</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><strong>¡Pandora abre la caja!</strong><br /> Liberadas para la eternidad las plagas de enfermedad y dolor. <a href="foo">Más...</a></li>
        <li><strong>Bienvenido a Helena.</strong><br /> El hijo de Prometeo escapa al diluvio y crea una sociadad en las piedras. <a href="foo">Más...</a></li>
        <li><strong>Una Red Enmarañada</strong><br /> Aracne pierde el hilo; se transforma en araña. <a href="">Más...</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="pie">
    <p>Contenido traducido de <cite>Old Greek Stories</cite> by James Baldwin (1914). It is a copyright free text available at <a href="http://www.gutenberg.net/1/1/5/8/11582/">Project Gutenberg</a>.
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muy bueno, pero ahora tengo un pequeño inconveniente, el texto del div #principal se sale del div si se hace el navegador muy pequeño

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!